# spark do calculation on column based on old values of previous row

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a given data frame like below

```
+----------------+---------------+----------+------------------+-------------+
|Transaction_date|    Added  date|coupon_id |cart_value        | coupon_value|
+----------------+---------------+----------+------------------+-------------+
|2018-01-16      |2018-02-01     |2390324796|12.5              |1.8          |
|2018-01-16      |2018-01-04     |1100111212|1.0               |2.0          |
|2018-01-19      |2018-01-04     |1100111212|2.5               |2.0          |
+----------------+---------------+----------+------------------+-------------+
```

I need to apply the coupon value to cart value and update the Coupon balance and auto redeemed value, this I want to do only when "Transaction_date" is greater than "Added Date" of a coupon value

**Logic**

UpdatedBalance = (coupon_value - cart_value ), if  cart_value is more, redeem only the available coupon value.

Redeemed = How much redeemed in the given transaction

I want something like this

```
+----------------+---------------+----------+------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|Transaction_date|    Added  date|coupon_id |cart_value        | coupon_value|UpdatedBalance|Redeemed      |
+----------------+---------------+----------+------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|2018-01-16      |2018-02-01     |2390324796|12.5              |1.8          |0            |0            |
|2018-01-16      |2018-01-04     |1100111212|1.0               |2.0          |1            |1            |
|2018-01-19      |2018-01-04     |1100111212|2.5               |2.0          |0            |1            |
+----------------+---------------+----------+------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

I am trying to do it in spark-scala

Comment: can you describe the logic to get updatedBalance and Redeemed columns? it is not clear from the explanation.

Comment: UpdatedBalance = (coupon_value - cart_value ), if    cart_value  is more redeem only available coupon ,  Redeemed = How much redeemed in the given transaction

Comment: can you add this info in the question?

Comment: what is the partition column?.

Answer (score 0):

With the assumption that the partition is on the entire table and ordered by added_date descending, below would work

```
scala> val df =Seq(("2018-01-16","2018-02-01",2390324796L,12.5,1.8),("2018-01-16","2018-01-04",1100111212L,1.0,2.0),("2018-01-19","2018-01-04",1100111212L,2.5,2.0)).toDF("Transaction_date","Added_date","coupon_id","cart_value","coupon_value")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [Transaction_date: string, Added_date: string ... 3 more fields]

scala> df.show(false)
+----------------+----------+----------+----------+------------+
|Transaction_date|Added_date|coupon_id |cart_value|coupon_value|
+----------------+----------+----------+----------+------------+
|2018-01-16      |2018-02-01|2390324796|12.5      |1.8         |
|2018-01-16      |2018-01-04|1100111212|1.0       |2.0         |
|2018-01-19      |2018-01-04|1100111212|2.5       |2.0         |
+----------------+----------+----------+----------+------------+


scala> val df2 = df.withColumn("UpdatedBalance",when('coupon_value>'cart_value,'coupon_value-'cart_value).otherwise(0))
df2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [Transaction_date: string, Added_date: string ... 4 more fields]

scala> df2.show(false)
+----------------+----------+----------+----------+------------+--------------+
|Transaction_date|Added_date|coupon_id |cart_value|coupon_value|UpdatedBalance|
+----------------+----------+----------+----------+------------+--------------+
|2018-01-16      |2018-02-01|2390324796|12.5      |1.8         |0.0           |
|2018-01-16      |2018-01-04|1100111212|1.0       |2.0         |1.0           |
|2018-01-19      |2018-01-04|1100111212|2.5       |2.0         |0.0           |
+----------------+----------+----------+----------+------------+--------------+

scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._


scala> df2.withColumn("Redeemed",sum('UpdatedBalance).over(Window.orderBy('Added_date.desc))).show(false)
19/01/03 10:31:50 WARN window.WindowExec: No Partition Defined for Window operation! Moving all data to a single partition, this can cause serious performance degradation.
+----------------+----------+----------+----------+------------+--------------+--------+
|Transaction_date|Added_date|coupon_id |cart_value|coupon_value|UpdatedBalance|Redeemed|
+----------------+----------+----------+----------+------------+--------------+--------+
|2018-01-16      |2018-02-01|2390324796|12.5      |1.8         |0.0           |0.0     |
|2018-01-16      |2018-01-04|1100111212|1.0       |2.0         |1.0           |1.0     |
|2018-01-19      |2018-01-04|1100111212|2.5       |2.0         |0.0           |1.0     |
+----------------+----------+----------+----------+------------+--------------+--------+


scala>
```